Science fiction novel where an expedition follows the tracks of an old civilization and finally meets the remnants of the race
I read it in the early 1980's. It is about an expedition to discover a race of beings who had colonised the galaxy in the past and wherever they went had created amazing civilisations and then moved on. The expedition tracked them all over the galaxy and everywhere they found evidence of them the beings had seemed to have recently left leaving no sign of themselves. At last they found the planet where the stupendous race had ended up only to find they were all old and dying. Does anyone remember anything like this?

This is a match, but the timescales are all wrong; https://www.amazon.co.uk/All-Stars-Grave-Greg-Curtis-ebook/dp/B0069PH8LY

It wasn't Across a Billion Years by Robert Silverberg?

It sounds like a Arthur C. Clarke novel I read a million years ago, but can't recall the name.

@PatWagnerDenver The City and the Stars, perhaps? But in that, they have simply left the galaxy.

The description reminds me of the Heritage Universe books by Charles Sheffield, but the initial trilogy was written in the early 90s.

@SQB  Yes, that's what I was thinking of.

Hi - it might be the robert silverberg novel - thanks - I will check - dave!

Maybe a book in the HeeChee series by Frederik Pohl? I have vague recollections of them tracking the remnants of the HeeChee civilization to the event horizon of a large (super massive?) black hole. (utilizing the time dilation to live normally while millions of years passed by outside the black hole.) But it has been Many years since I read them and I may have confused them with another book.

Hi - thankyou everyone and especially Alexander - it was the Silverberg novel, not exactly as I remember it but definitely the one I was looking for!
